# Set MultiIndex when aggregating using pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Some excercise is asking to "add a secondary name" to a df column when applying an aggregation function.

Given following DF:

```
stype = ['s1','s1','s1','s1',
    's2','s2','s2','s2']
dtype = ['d1','d1','d2','d2',
        'd1','d1','d2','d2']
qty = [2, 1.4, 7, 3, 
        4, 1, 2.0, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'s_type':stype,
                    'd_type':dtype,
                    'qty':qty})
```

When grouping by the first 2 columns and applying an agg function like this

```
new_df=df.groupby(['s_type','d_type'],sort =  False).agg({'qty':'median'})
```

And do print(new_df)

I get this output, notice the  `qty` is moved up a line (I assume this is normal behavior) because is the one column where agg function was applied

```
               qty
s_type d_type     
s1     d1      1.7
       d2      5.0
s2     d1      2.5
       d2      2.5
```

Question(s ) would it be

Is it possible to setc secondary column name under `qty` label/name ?, to get an output like this:

```
               qty
s_type d_type  Median   
s1     d1      1.7
       d2      5.0
s2     d1      2.5
       d2      2.5
```

Also
Why `qty` moves up 1 line ? (I'm using Spyder and I've seen this in the Anaconda/python console as well, not sure if its like a feature or pandas normal behavior).

**One Last update:** in case you need to use sort_values you will have to use the tuple for the column you add a secondary index/name, pretty much in the same way when applying the aggregate function (**see the answer**)

```
new_df=new_df.sort_values([('qty','MEDIAN')])
```

So you get the DF sorted by the column where agg function was applied and where we add an index

```
                 qty
              MEDIAN
s_type d_type       
s1     d1        1.7
s2     d1        2.5
       d2        2.5
s1     d2        5.0
```

**python v3.6**

**pandas v0.23**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super simple. Pass "median" as a list inside `agg`:

```
result = df.groupby(['s_type','d_type'], sort=False).agg({'qty': ['median']})
result
                 qty
              median
s_type d_type       
s1     d1        1.7
       d2        5.0
s2     d1        2.5
       d2        2.5
```

---

As for "why qty moves up 1 line", that means the first two columns are actually the *index* in the output. Querying `result.index` will make it obvious:

```
result.index

MultiIndex(levels=[['s1', 's2'], ['d1', 'd2']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['s_type', 'd_type'])
```

You can instead specify `as_index=False` when calling groupby,

```
df.groupby(['s_type','d_type'], sort=False, as_index=False).agg({'qty': ['median']})

  s_type d_type    qty
                median
0     s1     d1    1.7
1     s1     d2    5.0
2     s2     d1    2.5
3     s2     d2    2.5
```

So the groupers remain columns in the output.

---

You can change the name in the output by passing a list of tuples to `agg`:

```
df.groupby(['s_type','d_type'], sort=False).agg(
    {'qty': [('MEDIAN', 'median')]}
)

                 qty
              MEDIAN
s_type d_type       
s1     d1        1.7
       d2        5.0
s2     d1        2.5
       d2        2.5
```